# Building an ethereum based identity system

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, identity

Okay, I am still new to the web3 space, written a couple of smart contracts so far, but i want to take on a mid-sized project on building a decentralized identity management system on Ethereum Network, can anyone give me pointers or rather a roadmap on where i could start?. *I figured building projects is a faster way to learn.*

I was thinking a sort of a system that stores and validate user's credentials so that an institution is able to verify the credentials or data they have stored to be authentic and only the information needed by the institution is being given. The system has the following goals :

1. Able to Store User information.
2. Able to validate and protect digital identity of users.
3. Provide third-party only the information needed.
4. Able to Integrate with offline systems

Comment: What kind of identity or system do you have in mind? Users are typically identified by their address.

Comment: Thks for posting the question, please can you specify the question, as with this broad question is difficult to answer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.